assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
I'm creating a struct App that has two fields: One field contains an owned window (simplifed to an u32 here), the other field contains a struct that should eventually reference above window. However, when I try to fill in the struct in the resumed method, the compiler can't guarantee that self (lifetime of '1) will outlive the window reference 'a. For me this is quite obvious since the '1 will own window, thus the reference has the same lifetime '1.. so to say, but how to tell the compiler? I'm quite new to rust so I would be happy for a not so technical answer :)
Live Demo:
struct State<'a> {
    window: &'a u32
}

impl<'a> State<'a> {
    fn new(window: &'a u32) -> Self {
        State{
            window
        } 
    }
}


#[derive(Default)]
struct App<'a> {
    window: u32,
    state: Option<State<'a>>,
}


trait ApplicationHandler
{
    fn resumed(&mut self);
}


impl<'a> ApplicationHandler for App<'a> {

    fn resumed(&mut self) {
        self.window = 21;
        self.state = Some(State::new(&self.window))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut app = App::default();
    app.resumed();
}

This is the error I get:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> <source>:31:9
   |
27 | impl<'a> ApplicationHandler for App<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
28 |
29 |     fn resumed(&mut self) {
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
30 |         self.window = 21;
31 |         self.state = Some(State::new(&self.window))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`

error: aborting due to 1 previous error


You should avoid self-referential structs, which are technically possible but completely useless as they borrow themselves forever. There are crates like ouroboros that help you create self-referential types, but my recommendation would be to change the design of your program to just avoid self-referencing. The question looks like a duplicate of this question to me, which has a great ansewer.

@JonasFassbender I would love to, any suggestions how? My problem is that this example is somewhat borrowed from a tutorial and the ApplicationHandler is also not under my control (it's the one from winit)

If you can avoid that your State needs to borrow the Window, then there wouldn't be any self-references. Maybe you can store the WindowId of your Window instance in the State instead?
